# How refresh parent view when data is passed from child to parent

Tags: angular, typescript

I am passing a value from parent to child and tried getting the updated value from child to parent using the below code

```
<app-childcomments (CommentsChange)="Usercommentsmodel = $event" [Usercommentsmodel]="Usercommentsmodel"></app-childcomments>
```

that code seems to be not working and the view is not getting refreshed at parent and i tried directly assigning values in child but i am seeing duplicate values

```
this.usercommentsservice.deletecomment(commentdata).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('comment deleted');
      console.log(data);
      this.Usercommentsmodel = data;

    });
```

what is the best approach to pass values from child to parent and parent detects the changes and refreshes the view.

[check the link - error which iam seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1VYT.gif)

[image]

Comment: just write: `<app-childcomments [(Usercommentsmodel)]="Usercommentsmodel"></app-childcomments>`

Comment: @DanilSabirov thanks for the reply do we still need to have output passed from child to parent or can i directly change it?

Comment: in your example you can just delete it. We need an additional event hadler on parameter change if we have some additional logic than just data reassign

Comment: @DanilSabirov this is happening at ondelete(), i am able to delete items in database and get updated values, which i need to pass to parent but parent is not showing the updated values

Comment: well, can you apply @Ranjeet Jain solution and put additional console.log to see whether the event was fired or not

Comment: the is full code what i am triggering when i delete an item at child
`deletecomment(event: any) {
    const commentid = event.target.parentNode.childNodes[2].id;
    const commentdata: any = new FormData();
    commentdata.append('commentid', commentid);
    commentdata.append('userid', this.UserId);
    commentdata.append('postid', this.postid);
    this.usercommentsservice.deletecomment(commentdata).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('comment deleted');
      console.log(data);
      this.Usercommentsmodel = [];
      this.Usercommentsmodel = data;
    });
  }`

Comment: hmm. I can see your video with the demo. Can you replicate you problem on stackblitz? It would be much easier to fix a problem there

Comment: @DanilSabirov, i have a backend service which ipulls data and cannot call in Stackblitz

Comment: you can do a fake service

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in parent class and assign in template.
Try to change the value in parent class in Typescript code.

```
<app-childcomments (CommentsChange)="handleChange($event)" [Usercommentsmodel]="Usercommentsmodel"></app-childcomments>`
```

```
handleChange() {
  this.Usercommentmodel = $event; //assuming you are passing value in $event
}
```

More code snippet would help if this does not work. Assuming value changes in Child is because of user interaction.

Error which I am seeing:

[image: check the link - error which iam seeing]

Comment: i tried add the code to parent with output, but its not firing
`handleChange(event: Usercommentsmodel[]) {
      console.log('new data emitted from child to parent');
      this.Usercommentsmodel = event;
    }`
`<app-childcomments (CommentsChange)="handleChange($event)" [Usercommentsmodel]="Usercommentsmodel"></app-childcomments>`

at child
`this.CommentsChange.emit(data);`